# Nodejs and mysql, multiple criteria in a query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, coffeescript

I m actually using the mysql module to query my database and I m facing a problem. In fact, I need to escape a full object and parse it in a query that mysql could understand.

Actually, I have :

```
getByCriteria: (collectionName, criteria)->
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?'
    inserts = [collectionName, criteria]
    sql = MySql.format(sql, inserts)

    deferred = Q.defer()
    MysqlAdapter.CONNECTION.query(sql, (err, rows, fields)->
      console.log err
      if err
        deferred.reject(new Error(err))
      else
        deferred.resolve(rows)
    )
    return deferred.promise
```

But the console.log(sql) prints :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'admin', id=1
```

So I have guessed that the "Mysql.format" returns a string for the INSERT/UPDATE SQL actions.
How can I do it with mysql, without parsing the entire string with a homemade solution ?

THanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that `MySql.format()` is very simple (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/protocol/SqlString.js#L67) so you'll need to do your own formatting.

Just remember to escape values with `MySql.escape()` and identifiers with `MySql.escapeId()`

You'll need something similar to `SqlString.objectToValues()` https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/protocol/SqlString.js#L109 but with values joined with `AND` instead of `,`